# PyQT5 программа закрывается при нажатии Esc

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qdialog

Любая программа, созданная в *Qt Designer* и импортированная в код *Python* при нажатии **`Escape`** закрывается.

Как убрать это?

Пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **QDialog Class**
>
> Класс QDialog является базовым классом диалоговых окон.

---

> **Escape Key**
>
> Если пользователь нажимает клавишу `Esc` в диалоговом окне, вызывается `QDialog::reject()`. Это приведет к закрытию окна: **событие закрытия нельзя игнорировать**.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#escape-key

---

**Update**

Но вы можете при создании формы в `QT Designer` наследоваться от виджета отличного от `QDialog`, например `QWidget`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 341, 32))
        
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Form)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        
        self.buttonCancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.buttonOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Ok")
        
        self.buttonBox.addButton(self.buttonCancel, QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.RejectRole)
        self.buttonBox.addButton(self.buttonOk, QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)

        self.buttonOk.clicked.connect(lambda : self.label.setText('Ok'))
        self.buttonCancel.clicked.connect(lambda: self.label.setText('Cancel'))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QWidget()                                  # - QDialog()  + QWidget
    
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете переопределить обработку события нажатия клавиши ESC для QDialog, например, вот так:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, a0: QKeyEvent) -> None:

    if a0.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
        return
    else:
        return super().keyPressEvent(a0)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Переопределить где, в Qt Designer ?

Comment: В классе диалога своего приложения.